# mysql php date math (dateandtimeA - dateandtimeB)

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, math, date

I am working on a time system where I need to take the time someone punches in to when some on punches out

```
i.e 2011-05-20 08:30:00 (punch in time) - 2011-05-20 17:30:00 = X hrs
or  2011-05-20 09:45:00                 - 2011-05-25 17:57:00 = X days Y hrs
```

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: That's good for the dates (handy billing) how about time differences?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly: [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Then: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

In SQL: http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/func_datediff_mysql.asp